# Why the input code the player enter is a sum of something the value is 80 and not a number(12345678)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this script I set the maximum code length in this case 8.
Then I build the code from a onmousekeydown events.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SecurityKeypadSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    // rather let this class control the display text
    [SerializeField] private TextMesh _text;

    [Header("Settings")]
    // also rather let this class control the length of a code
    [SerializeField] private int _codeLength = 8;

    [Header("Debugging")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _keyPadNumbers;
    [SerializeField] private List<int> _code = new List<int>();

    // This will be invoked once the code length has reached the target length
    public event Action<int> OnCodeComplete;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        var KeyPadNumbersParent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("KeypadParent").GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);
        foreach (Transform child in KeyPadNumbersParent)
        {
            if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>() != null)
            {
                var securityKeypadKeys = child.gameObject.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>();
                securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed -= HandleKeyPressed;
                securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed += HandleKeyPressed;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // just for completeness you should always remove callbacks as soon as they are not needed anymore
        // in order to avoid any exceptions
        foreach (var keyPadNumber in _keyPadNumbers)
        {
            var securityKeypadKeys = keyPadNumber.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>();
            securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed -= HandleKeyPressed;
        }
    }

    // this is called when a keypad key was pressed
    private void HandleKeyPressed(int value)
    {
        // add the value to the list
        _code.Add(value);
        _text.text += value.ToString();

        // Check if the code has reached the target length
        // if yes prcoess further
        if (_code.Count == _codeLength)
        {
            // if it reached the length combine all numbers into one int
            var exponent = _code.Count;
            float finalCode = 0;
            foreach (var digit in _code)
            {
                finalCode = digit * Mathf.Pow(10, exponent);
                exponent--;
            }

            // invoke the callback event
            OnCodeComplete?.Invoke((int)finalCode);

            // and reset the code
            StartCoroutine(ResetCodeTime());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ResetCodeTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        ResetCode();
    }

    // Maybe you later want an option to clear the code field from the outside as well
    public void ResetCode()
    {
        _code.Clear();
        _text.text = "";
    }

    // also clear the input if this gets disabled
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        ResetCode();
    }
}
```

Inside the method HandleKeyPressed I build the code. If the player entered 12345678 this what _code should be and if the player enter 67344477 then this should be the entered code.

This script is using event to get the pressed numbers of the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine;

public class SecurityKeypadKeys : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int _number;

    public event Action<int> onKeyPressed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        name = $"Key {_number}";
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        onKeyPressed?.Invoke(_number);
    }
}
```

And this script I'm checking if the given code the _targetCode is equal to the input code the player entered :

For example the code now is 12345678

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class UnlockCrate : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private int _targetCode;

    public GameObject securityKeyPad;
    public GameObject player;
    public Animation anim;
    public IKControl ikControl;
    public InteractableItem interactableItem;
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCam;
    public CinemachineFreeLook freeLookCam;
    public CamerasControl camerasContorl;

    private bool playAnimOnce = false;

    [SerializeField] private SecurityKeypadSystem securityKeypadSystem;

    private void Start()
    {
        // as before attach a handler that is triggered once the system completes one code
        securityKeypadSystem.OnCodeComplete -= HandleInputCode;
        securityKeypadSystem.OnCodeComplete += HandleInputCode;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        securityKeypadSystem.OnCodeComplete -= HandleInputCode;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (distance <= interactableItem.distance)
        {
            if (!playAnimOnce)
            {
                if (ikControl.handFinishedMove == true)
                {
                    securityKeyPad.SetActive(true);
                    virtualCam.enabled = true;
                    freeLookCam.enabled = false;
                    Cursor.visible = true;
                    camerasContorl.enabled = false;

                    /*if(securityKeyPad.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>().UnlockedCode() == true)
                    {
                        securityKeyPad.SetActive(false);
                        virtualCam.enabled = false;
                        freeLookCam.enabled = true;
                        Cursor.visible = false;
                        anim.Play("Crate_Open");
                    }*/


                    //anim.Play("Crate_Open");
                    playAnimOnce = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (playAnimOnce)
        {
            securityKeyPad.SetActive(false);
            virtualCam.enabled = false;
            freeLookCam.enabled = true;
            Cursor.visible = false;
            camerasContorl.enabled = true;
            anim.Play("Crate_Close");
            playAnimOnce = false;
        }
    }

    private void HandleInputCode(int inputCode)
    {
        if (inputCode == _targetCode)
        {
            Debug.Log("Code correct!", this);
            anim.Play("Crate_Open");
            // TODO whatelse has to be done
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"WRONG CODE: Expected {_targetCode} but was {inputCode}!", this);
            // TODO some wrong code animation?
        }
    }
}
```

At the bottom I'm doing the checking inside the HandleInputCode method :

```
if (inputCode == _targetCode)
```

The _targetCode is a number 12345678 but the inputCode value is 80 and not what the player entered.
Not sure where the 80 is came from if the player typed 12345678

[image: Checking the entered code against the target code]

Comment: Something with this calculation line finalCode = digit * Mathf.Pow(10, exponent); is wrong or not calculating as it should be. This make in the end the code result 80. I used a break point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trace through how this loop will run

```
var exponent = _code.Count;
float finalCode = 0;
foreach (var digit in _code)
{
    finalCode = digit * Mathf.Pow(10, exponent);
    exponent--;
}
```

Assuming `_code` is 12345678, then `exponent` starts out as 8 and your loop runs 8 times.  On the final iteration of your loop, `digit` will be 8 and `exponent` will be 1.  Hence:

```
finalCode = digit * Mathf.Pow(10, exponent);
finalCode = 8 * Mathf.Pow(10, 1);
finalCode = 8 * 10;
finalCode = 80;
```

Did you mean to use a `+=` instead of `=` in the line `finalCode = digit * Mathf.Pow(10, exponent);`

Additionally, I think you should be initializing `exponent` to `_code.Count - 1`.  instead of `_code.Count`.  If you start `exponent` at 8, you will be doing this:

```
1 * 100000000 +
2 *  10000000 +
3 *   1000000 +
4 *    100000 +
5 *     10000 +
6 *      1000 +
7 *       100 +
8 *        10
-------------
    123456780
```

What you really want is

```
1 * 10000000 +
2 *  1000000 +
3 *   100000 +
4 *    10000 +
5 *     1000 +
6 *      100 +
7 *       10 +
8 *        1
------------
    12345678
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of out-by-one: while the string has 8 digits, the highest exponent is actually 7 (and the lowest is 0, not 1). Thus `exponent` should be initialized to `_code.Count - 1`. Then, in your loop `exponent` will count down from 7 to 0 and `finalCode` (if set using `+=` instead of `=`) will have the right value.

Another (and faster, actually) way of doing the conversion is

```
int finalCode = 0;
foreach (var digit in _code) {
    finalCode *= 10;
    finalCode += digit;
}
```

This will work for any base (just change the 10 to the base (or better, use a `base` variable)) assuming `digit` correctly represents a digit in that base.